# Differences between IN and [;database=] in SQL ACCESS

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

Whats the difference between IN command in SQL and [;database=] to join data from external databases like ACCESS?
eg:

```
select * from table1 in 'c:\data.accdb'
```

and

```
select * from [;database=c:\data.accdb].table1
```

Using one of those can block the external database on shared disk?

eg:
One of users is blocking access to file for others

If not, what could possibly block the file this way?

Comment: why don't you just link table1 in your front-end database ?

Comment: I think that generally linked table are the easiest solution. Just pay attention that if you combine tables from 2 different sources (e.g. 2 different SQL Servers) it can have a strong negative impact on performance. Same issue if your 2 tables connect to the same DB but with - even the smallest - difference in the connect string.

Comment: I know, that I can use Linked Tables, but I'm looking for other ways to connect data ( maybe faster ways ).

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN` syntax seems to apply to all tables in the query, while the 2d syntax seems to be usable on a table by table basis. Also, the `IN` has the advantage of being a property of the query, making changes to the target BE easy to program.
Eg, with 2 tables, both in external db:

```
SELECT tblIssues.IssueId, tblStatus.StatusDescription
FROM tblStatus INNER JOIN tblIssues ON tblStatus.StatusID = tblIssues.Status
IN 'H:\Documents\MyFolder\Mydb_BE.accdb';
```

I don't know if the exclusive use of the FE propagates to the BE.
And again: why not just using linked tables ?

Comment: I find that you can connect to a lot more stuff (Excel, MySQL etc, etc) with `[connection]` in a lot more Office applications than you can with `IN`